# c++ sqlite3 wrapper

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

this is a simple wrapper for sqlite3 to make working with databases easier
it isn't a professional implementation but it is much better than the raw c interface
I saved much time and code using this wrapper instead of the raw interface
any improvements will be appreciated

HandleBase.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, T null_value, bool no_negative = true>
class HandleWrapper
{
public:
    HandleWrapper() : handle(null_value)
    {}
    HandleWrapper(T h) : handle(h)
    {
        if constexpr (no_negative)
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
            {
                if constexpr (null_value >= 0)
                {
                    if (handle < 0)
                        handle = null_value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if constexpr ((intptr_t)null_value >= 0)
                {
                    if ((intptr_t)handle < 0)
                        handle = null_value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool operator==(const HandleWrapper& rhs)
    {
        return handle == rhs.handle;
    }

    bool operator!=(const HandleWrapper& rhs)
    {
        return handle != rhs.handle;
    }

    bool operator>(const HandleWrapper& rhs)
    {
        return handle > rhs.handle;
    }

    bool operator>=(const HandleWrapper& rhs)
    {
        return handle >= rhs.handle;
    }

    bool operator<(const HandleWrapper& rhs)
    {
        return handle < rhs.handle;
    }

    bool operator<=(const HandleWrapper& rhs)
    {
        return handle < rhs.handle;
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return handle != null_value;
    }

    operator T()
    {
        return handle;
    }

private:
    T handle;
};

template <class T, T null_value, bool no_negative, auto Deleter>
struct HandleHelper
{
    using pointer = HandleWrapper<T, null_value, no_negative>;
    void operator()(pointer p)
    {
        Deleter(T(p));
    }
};
```

sqlite++.h

```
#pragma once
#include <HandleBase.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string>

using SqlHandle = std::unique_ptr<HandleWrapper<sqlite3*, nullptr, false>, HandleHelper<sqlite3*, nullptr, false, sqlite3_close> >;

using SqlStatementHandle = std::unique_ptr<HandleWrapper<sqlite3_stmt*, nullptr, false>, HandleHelper<sqlite3_stmt*, nullptr, false, sqlite3_finalize>>;

enum class SqlOpenFlags
{
    Read = SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,
    ReadWrite = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,
    ReadWriteCreate = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,
};

class SqlDb
{
    SqlHandle handle;
public:
    SqlDb() {}
    SqlDb(const std::string& path);
    SqlDb(const std::wstring& path);
    SqlDb(const std::string& path, SqlOpenFlags flags);
    SqlDb(SqlDb&& rhs) : handle(std::move(rhs.handle)) {}

    SqlDb& operator=(SqlDb&& rhs)
    {
        handle = std::move(rhs.handle);
        return *this;
    }

    bool Open(const std::string& path);

    bool Open(const std::wstring& path);

    bool Open(const std::string& path, SqlOpenFlags flags);

    void Close()
    {
        handle.reset();
    }

    explicit operator bool() const { return bool(handle); }

    sqlite3 * native_handle() { return handle.get(); }

    SqlHandle Release() { return std::move(handle); }

    int ErrorCode();

    int ErrorCodeExt();

    std::string ErrorStr();

    std::wstring ErrorStrW();

};


class SqlQuery
{
    SqlStatementHandle statement;
    std::string statement_str;

public :
    SqlQuery() {}
    SqlQuery(SqlDb& db, const char *stmt, ...);
    SqlQuery(SqlDb& db, const wchar_t *stmt, ...);
    SqlQuery(SqlQuery&& rhs) : statement(std::move(rhs.statement)) {}

    bool Prepare(SqlDb& db, const char *stmt, ...);
    bool Prepare(SqlDb& db, const wchar_t *stmt, ...);

    void Close() { statement.reset(); }

    sqlite3_stmt * native_handle() { return statement.get(); }

    SqlStatementHandle Release() { return std::move(statement); }

    explicit operator bool() const { return bool(statement); }

    std::string GetStatement();

    bool execute();

    bool next();

    int ColumnsCount();

    int ColumnSize(int index);

    std::string GetStr(int index);

    std::wstring GetStrW(int index);

    int GetInt(int index);

    int64_t GetInt64(int index);

    double GetDouble(int index);

    const void *GetBlob(int index);

};
```

sqlite++.cpp

```
#include "sqlite++.h"

using namespace std;

SqlDb::SqlDb(const std::string & path)
{
    sqlite3 *temp_handle;
    sqlite3_open(path.c_str(), &temp_handle);
    handle.reset(temp_handle);
}

SqlDb::SqlDb(const std::wstring & path)
{
    sqlite3 *temp_handle;
    sqlite3_open16(path.c_str(), &temp_handle);
    handle.reset(temp_handle);
}

SqlDb::SqlDb(const std::string & path, SqlOpenFlags flags)
{
    sqlite3 *temp_handle;
    sqlite3_open_v2(path.c_str(), &temp_handle, (int)flags, nullptr);
    handle.reset(temp_handle);
}

bool SqlDb::Open(const std::string & path)
{
    sqlite3 *temp_handle;
    sqlite3_open(path.c_str(), &temp_handle);
    handle.reset(temp_handle);
    return bool(handle);
}

bool SqlDb::Open(const std::wstring & path)
{
    sqlite3 *temp_handle;
    sqlite3_open16(path.c_str(), &temp_handle);
    handle.reset(temp_handle);
    return bool(handle);
}

bool SqlDb::Open(const std::string & path, SqlOpenFlags flags)
{
    sqlite3 *temp_handle;
    sqlite3_open_v2(path.c_str(), &temp_handle, (int)flags, nullptr);
    handle.reset(temp_handle);
    return bool(handle);
}

int SqlDb::ErrorCode()
{
    return sqlite3_errcode(handle.get());
}

int SqlDb::ErrorCodeExt()
{
    return sqlite3_extended_errcode(handle.get());
}

std::string SqlDb::ErrorStr()
{
    return sqlite3_errmsg(handle.get());
}

std::wstring SqlDb::ErrorStrW()
{
    return (wchar_t*)sqlite3_errmsg16(handle.get());
}

SqlQuery::SqlQuery(SqlDb & db, const char * stmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, stmt);
    size_t required_size = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, stmt, args);
    if (!required_size)
        return;
    unique_ptr<char> buff(new char[required_size + 1]);
    vsnprintf(buff.get(), required_size + 1, stmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    sqlite3_stmt *temp_stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db.native_handle(), buff.get(), -1, &temp_stmt, nullptr);
    statement_str = buff.get();
    statement.reset(temp_stmt);
}

SqlQuery::SqlQuery(SqlDb & db, const wchar_t * stmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, stmt);
    size_t required_size = vswprintf(nullptr, 0, stmt, args);
    if (!required_size)
        return;
    unique_ptr<wchar_t> buff(new wchar_t[required_size + 1]);
    vswprintf(buff.get(), required_size + 1, stmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    sqlite3_stmt *temp_stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare16_v2(db.native_handle(), buff.get(), -1, &temp_stmt, nullptr);
    statement.reset(temp_stmt);
}

bool SqlQuery::Prepare(SqlDb & db, const char * stmt, ...)
{
    statement.reset();
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, stmt);
    size_t required_size = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, stmt, args);
    if (!required_size)
        return false;
    unique_ptr<char> buff(new char[required_size + 1]);
    vsnprintf(buff.get(), required_size + 1, stmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    sqlite3_stmt *temp_stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db.native_handle(), buff.get(), -1, &temp_stmt, nullptr);
    statement_str = buff.get();
    statement.reset(temp_stmt);
    return bool(statement);
}

bool SqlQuery::Prepare(SqlDb & db, const wchar_t * stmt, ...)
{
    statement.reset();
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, stmt);
    size_t required_size = vswprintf(nullptr, 0, stmt, args);
    if (!required_size)
        return false;
    unique_ptr<wchar_t> buff(new wchar_t[required_size + 1]);
    vswprintf(buff.get(), required_size + 1, stmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    sqlite3_stmt *temp_stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare16_v2(db.native_handle(), buff.get(), -1, &temp_stmt, nullptr);
    statement.reset(temp_stmt);
    return bool(statement);
}

std::string SqlQuery::GetStatement()
{
    return statement_str;
    //const char *str = sqlite3_sql(statement.get()); always returns null , don't know why ?
    //return str ? string(str) : string();
}

bool SqlQuery::execute()
{
    return sqlite3_step(statement.get()) == SQLITE_DONE;
}

bool SqlQuery::next()
{
    return sqlite3_step(statement.get()) == SQLITE_ROW;
}

int SqlQuery::ColumnsCount()
{
    return sqlite3_column_count(statement.get());
}

int SqlQuery::ColumnSize(int index)
{
    return sqlite3_column_bytes(statement.get(), index);
}

std::string SqlQuery::GetStr(int index)
{
    const char *str = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement.get(), index);
    return str ? string(str) : string();
}

std::wstring SqlQuery::GetStrW(int index)
{
    const wchar_t *str = (wchar_t*)sqlite3_column_text16(statement.get(), index);
    return str ? wstring(str) : wstring();
}

int SqlQuery::GetInt(int index)
{
    return sqlite3_column_int(statement.get(), index);
}

int64_t SqlQuery::GetInt64(int index)
{
    return sqlite3_column_int64(statement.get(), index);
}

double SqlQuery::GetDouble(int index)
{
    return sqlite3_column_double(statement.get(), index);
}

const void * SqlQuery::GetBlob(int index)
{
    return sqlite3_column_blob(statement.get(), index);
}
```